How to define $\mathbb{H}^2$-rotation about any point?
In the book Geometry of Surfaces by Stillwell, he defines the $\mathbb{H}^2$-rotation about $i$ in view of the conformal disc $\mathbb{D}^2$. Specifically, let
$$ J(z):=\frac{iz+1}{z+i}$$
be the fractional linear transformation mapping $\mathbb{H}^2$ to $\mathbb{D}^2$. Let $r_\theta(z):=e^{i\theta}z$ be the (Euclidean) rotation on $\mathbb{D}^2$. By checking it leaves the Riemannian metric invariant, we see that $r_\theta$ is a $\mathbb{D}^2$-isometry. Therefore, $J^{-1}r_\theta J$ becomes a $\mathbb{H}^2$-isometry, called a $\mathbb{H}^2$-rotation about $i$.
My question is, how to define $\mathbb{H}^2$-rotation about any point $P$ in a similar way? (I notice that in this book the author also mentioned that we can choose 'suitable coordinates' in $\mathbb{H}^2$, but I don't see why and how. Maybe we  define $\mathbb{H}^2$-rotation about any point $P$ by choosing 'suitable coordinates' such that $P$ goes to $i$?)
Thanks for your help!

Shifting the upper half-plane horizontally is an isometry. So is rescaling vertically. Using these two isometries, it is easy to find an isometry that moves $P$ to $i$. Now you do the same thing you’ve already done. Move $P$ to $i$, rotate, and move $i$ back to $P$.

Thank you! I agree.

@Deane. I would like to encourage you to post that explanation as an answer. Yes, it is  a very natural process, but unless we have covered it earlier, it would be nice to have it. If for no other reason that to get this question wrapped up. Your call, of course.
